# What Linux program(s) support OpenType alternate glyphs and can explode to vector shapes?

Tags: linux, vector-graphics, graphic-design, font-utility, desktop-publishing

I need some Linux based program that will allow me to create an assortment of drawings exported in SVG as exploded shapes that are primarily composed of a couple of words of text rendered with a few effects. Normally I would have used [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) for this, but the catch is I need to use some alternate glyphs (swash capitals) from an OpenType font and Inkscape does [not seem to support this yet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/627240).

What options do I have for this on Linux short of stealing a friend's Mac or running a VM to use InDesign?

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like LaTex provides support for all(most) all the OpenType font variants, including swash, you can either generate your graphics directly in LaTeX or generate the elements and [import into Inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX) then position them.

You may need to add some supplementary programs to be able to do the latter with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive pstoedit
```